# Xamarin android data saving to json file

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, save

I need to save the file when method `OnDestroy` is called and load same file when method `OnCreate` is called. At this time I can read `json` file easily from Assets (this works fine)

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("reiksmes.json"));
string JSONstring = reader.ReadToEnd();
Daiktai myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Daiktai>(JSONstring);
items.Add(myList);
```

, but I have some problems when I try to save(write) `Daiktai` class data to the same file I opened above. I tried:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
File.WriteAllText("Assets\\reiksmes.json", data);
```

> with this try I get error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Assets
>   eiksmes.json" is denied.`

also tried:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Assets.Open("reiksmes.json"));
writer.WriteLine(data);
```

> and with this try I get error `System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.`

Summary:
I think I chose bad directory(`Assets`), I need to save and load data (`json` format). So where do I need to save them and how(give example)?

Comment: Assets are files that are included in the app bundle, and are read only

Comment: so where do I need to save files and can you give me example how to save them?

Comment: Assets are read only, but in your string you've got '\r' it should be '\\r' to avoid it being a newline

Comment: It'll need to be a resource - this should be useful https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save anything to assets. You can just read from it. You have to save the file to a different folder.

```
        var fileName = "reiksmes.json";
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);

        Console.WriteLine(path);
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {                
            var s = AssetManager.Open(fileName);
            // create a write stream
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            // write to the stream
            ReadWriteStream(s, writeStream);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, it's working, but where I can find this file now on my computer ?

Comment: Do you mean browsing device file system on your computer?

Comment: For example if I want to modify this file by my own, where I do need to search it to open this file?

Comment: Do you mean through code? If so, the path that I construct in my example is where the file is.

Comment: No*. For example to open like this file : https://gyazo.com/3613fbabdc4e1ddb517cf6b925115b35

Comment: As I said before, just use the System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) and combine it with file name and that's where your file is and you can read from and write to.